# Value of _fmode different in Release and Debug Configurations

Tags: c, stdio, visual-studio-2022

I am working with a C codebase that uses `fopen` to do text file i/o. I cannot modify the codebase. (It is the source code of Lua 5.2.4.) It calls `fopen("filename", "r")`.

In my Visual Studio 2022 builds I am encountering a very weird discrepancy between the `Debug` and `Release` configurations. The `_fmode` global variable that determines the default open mode for `fopen` is set to text (0x4000: `_O_TEXT`) in the Debug configuration but binary (0x8000: `_O_BINARY`) in the Release configuration. I have been unable to determine any difference between the two that might cause this.

Does anyone have any ideas? I know I can override the value of `_fmode` in my code, but I'd like to get to the bottom of why this is happening. It may point to other issues.

I was able to isolate the behavior outside the Lua code (which is not easy to present without entanglements.) This code exhibits the issue:

```cpp
   FILE * myFile = fopen("a-file-that-has-2-lines-of-text", "r");
   if (myFile)
   {
      char buf[4096];
      fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), myFile);
      printf("Final 2 bytes of line: %d %d", buf[strlen(buf)-2], buf[strlen(buf)-1]);
   }
```

Comment: Discrepancy between different build configurations is often a result of bugs causing undefined behavior. You are not showing any code, so I am not sure how you expect us to help you any further.

Comment: Okay I added code. I doubt it will illuminate the problem. But it did occur to me that maybe I should check the behavior with a different file.

Comment: What is `DIM`? How do you know the value of `_fopen` and why exactly do you care about it?

Comment: Whoops, I meant `_fmode`. I've replaced `DIM` with `sizeof` (which does the same thing for `char` arrays.) About `_fmode` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/fmode?view=msvc-170

Comment: That's a nice find patters.  I have always opened text files "rt" so never stumbled onto the issue.  You might want to take your issue up with Microsoft.  Provide a test program that shows the mode and the behavior depending on how you compile it.

Comment: @rpatters1 From your link, this seems apropos:  "Link with Binmode.obj. This changes the initial setting of `_fmode` to `_O_BINARY`, causing all files except `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` to be opened in binary mode."  I suspect your release configuration might differ from your debug configuration, causing the release configuration to link to `binmode.obj` somehow.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I agree that looks promising. But I can't find any reference to it in my project. The list of libraries used for linking is the same for both configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone finds this question looking for a way to solve it, you can make certain the value of `_fmode` is `_O_TEXT` by adding this line of code in your initialization. (I added it in the DLL initialization routine of my project.)

```cpp
#include <fcntl.h>
.
.
.
_set_fmode(_O_TEXT);
```

I still do not know if this discrepancy is a bug in the C++ runtime or something weird about my project. But adding that line of code solved it for me.